# my javascript is not working but my validator says my code is fine and there are no syntax errors what do i do?

Tags: javascript, html

I was following a tutorial to make a responsive website  and it was working fine until i got to Javascript
I have followed the tutorial to a t but my code is still not working
i have tried several Javascript validators but all of them are saying that the cose is fine and there are no syntax errors
Here is the tutorial i was following:
[The tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeYpK.png)

and here is my code:

```js
var menuBtn = document.getElementById(menuBtn);
var sideNav = document.getElementById(sideNav);
var menuImg = document.getElementById(menuImg);

menuBtn.onclick = function(){
     if(sideNav.style.right == "-250px"){
         sideNav.style.right = "0";
     }
     else{
        sideNav.style.right = "-250px";
     }
};
```

Comment: `var menuBtn = document.getElementById(menuBtn);` should be `var menuBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn");` your are missing all the `"`  in the first 3 lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an element by id, the id value should be as a string (or variable with string value). your code misses the string quotes:

```js
document.getElementById("menuBtn");
```

Another thing, you can add `defer` attribute to your script HTML tag to load the HTML content before javascript:

```html
<script src="index.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing quotes from the document.getElementById(menuBtn); Should it be:

```
document.getElementById("menuBtn");
```

or similar?